# How to export data from real device to CSV?

Tags: android, sqlite, csv, export-to-csv

I wonder how to export data from real device to `CSV` ?

I using real device to run my app, and now I want to export all the data to CSV. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, keep on writing the data to a CSV file on the SD Card, and either export it through email or any others means.

You can see the example [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/apache/commons/csv-commons/writeread-csv-files-with-apache-commons-csv-example/) on how to convert data into CSV and saving it to a file.

Comment: Can you provide some link to me ? I don't understand what do you meant by  _writing the data to a CSV file on the SD Card_

Comment: There are plenty on the internet, google for examples on how to create CSVs using Java.